# Logout Shortcode URL

Tags: functions

I am trying to create a shortcode which gives the logout URL so I can place it on the widget area. I came up with this but I am getting a parse error. Also is this syntax aprropriate for what I want to achieve?

```
function logout_link()
{
    return sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" title="Logout">Logout</a>',
        wp_logout_url( home_url() ))
      }
add_shortcode( 'logout-shortcode', 'logout_link' );
```

Comment: You're missing a ;  I guess the errors tells you that?

Comment: no, i am using atom and the parser doesn't work for some reason, and i don't want to break the live site! But is the code factually correct apart from missing ; ?

Comment: what is the full text of that parse error?